# The evaluation process in normal order(Scheme)?

Tags: scheme, sicp

I'm studying SICP, and ex1.20 gives the following code:

```
    (define (gcd a b)
      (if (= b 0)
        a
        (gcd b (remainder a b))))
```

The question asks about the times remainder is called when we run `(gcd 206 40)` in applicative order and normal order, respectively. I can figure out remainder is called 4 times in applicative order, but I can't understand why it becomes 18 when it comes to normal order. In my view, first `(gcd 40 (remainder 206 40))`is called, and next we need to calculate `(remainder 206 40)`, which is 6, if we want to know which branch we go to, and then `(remainder 40 6)`, and so on, and it turns out to be 4 times, too. But the answer gives the following process:

```
     (gcd 206 40) 

     (if (= 40 0) ...) 

     (gcd 40 (remainder 206 40)) 

     (if (= (remainder 206 40) 0) ...) 

     (if (= 6 0) ...) 

     (gcd (remainder 206 40) (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40))) 

     (if (= (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40)) 0) ...) 

     (if (= 4 0) ...) 

     (gcd (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40)) (remainder (remainder 206 40) (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40)))) 

     (if (= (remainder (remainder 206 40) (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40))) 0) ...) 

     (if (= 2 0) ...) 

     (gcd (remainder (remainder 206 40) (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40))) (remainder (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40)) (remainder (remainder 206 40) (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40))))) 

     (if (= (remainder (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40)) (remainder (remainder 206 40) (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40)))) 0) ...) 

     (if (= 0 0) ...) 
     (remainder (remainder 206 40) (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40)))
```

So in total it's 18 times.
I think the main difference between the two answers is that I think once a remainder is calculated, then it won't need to be calculated any more, but the answer might seem to calculate it every time. Is this a matter of compiler? Isn't this too efficientless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edit*: actually, what I described as normal order is *call-by-name*. Lazy is *call-by-need* and both are indeed normal order.

---

Your intuition is correct for applicative order, where arguments are evaluated (i.e. their value is found out) *before* a function call. But in normal order they are only evaluated *inside* the function call, when their value is needed - and then, this value is forgotten. Normal order which remembers the found values is known as *lazy* evalution, by the way.

Thus, the reduction sequence for applicative order of evaluation is

```
> (gcd 206 40)
= (if (= 40 0) 206 (gcd 40 (remainder 206 40)))
= (gcd 40 (remainder 206 40))
> (remainder 206 40) => 6
= (gcd 40 6)
= (if (= 6 0) 40 (gcd 6 (remainder 40 6)))
= (gcd 6 (remainder 40 6))
> (remainder 40 6) => 4
= (gcd 6 4)
....
```

But for the normal order it'll be

```
> (gcd 206 40)
= (if (= 40 0) 206 (gcd 40 (remainder 206 40)))
= (gcd 40 (remainder 206 40))
= (if (= (remainder 206 40) 0) 40 
                   (gcd (remainder 206 40) (remainder 40 (remainder 206 40))))
....
```

You can see the difference.

Comment: Ah I got it, so you mean the value produced by remainder won't be saved in normal order. Then if I add a "delay" or "force" to the parameter, then remainder should also be called 4 times even in normal order.

Comment: you can put a delay on it, but it is the *system* which calls it, and *it* has no `force` and calls no `force` under normal order. If you can add some memoization mechanism on top of your values, then the system will still ask for it 18 (or whatver) times, but your memoized value will already be ready and waiting there for 2nd time on (so `remainder` would indeed get called only 4 times). -- if you put this forcing and delaying into your "system" (i.e. implementation) then you will have implemented the lazy evaluation strategy, not the normal order.

Comment: Ah yeah I know what you mean, so if I use lazy evaluation to the system, remainder will still be called 18 times but it will only calculate 4 times for the value has been stored. But I don't understand what you said about lazy evaluation, or call-by-need. I googled it and I think it's only a matter of function implementation, what does it do with normal order?

Comment: Re-reading [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Normal_order), I guess both are normal order, and whether we use call-by-name or call-by-need is a matter of implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much. Well-written explanation!